# deferredjs folder in the GWT compiled folder

Tags: java, gwt

I'm deploying my GWT application in a CMS, and thus copy files from the compiled folder, I don't copy the folder `deferredjs` but still the app works fine, What is this folder for and why does it contain many subfolders which folder names are like GUID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It contains portions of code which will be loaded asynchronously when needed. It is a way to have smaller portions of javascript. Read this [page](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting) to get more info.

If your app works is because either you are not using that code (it even could be part of a 3 party component), or either the loading is failing and you are not raising any error when it fails.